# Download big files with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried the following

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/4/8/648EB83C-00F9-49B2-806D-E46033DA4AE6/ExchangeServer2016-CU1.iso" -OutFile "Exchange.iso"

But this Fails with "OutOfMemory".

Then i tried -TransferEncoding "chunked" which tells me that i have to set the "SendChunked" property first.

The Documentation doesn't tell how, where and when to set this property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell limits remote connections (to around 128MB for older versions). You can increase that limit by using `Set-Item .\MaxMemoryPerShellMB` . But this may not fix the problem for very large files.

Best option for those would be to use BITS

Example:

```
$url = "http://files.net/test/file1.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\file1.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

Import-Module BitsTransfer

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
***OR***
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Alternately, try .Net.WebClient:

```
$url = "http://files.net/test/file1.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\file1.test"
$start_time = Get-Date
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
    ***OR***
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)

    Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: I understand that, but this is more likely an Workaround as None of them tell me the Progress (which Invoke-WebRequest does). Most Download Clients chunk their Downloads and Invoke-WebRequest also have this Features, i just dont know how to use it

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest was designed for small files and it's speed is very slow. Note that BITS can show progress, because Write-Progress cmdlet can be used along with it. I will add an example if you want.

Answer (score 1):

BitsTransfer works for large files. Here is an example using Write-Progress. Once the job has been started and a reference is obtained ($download), you can interact with it to show download progress. I found Complete-BitsTransfer necessary as a follow up, since without it files were given names like 'BIT52DB.tmp' instead of 'exampleFile.zip'.

```
$output = "C:\ProgramFiles\LocalPath\exampleFile.zip";
$download = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous
while ($download.JobState -ne "Transferred") { 
    [int] $dlProgress = ($download.BytesTransferred / $download.BytesTotal) * 100;
    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading File..." -Status "$dlProgress% Complete:" -PercentComplete $dlProgress; 
}
Complete-BitsTransfer $download.JobId;
```

Comment: Beware however that Bits transfers only work when the user is logged in. So if you plan on using it in any kind of scheduled task, it will not work unless the user running the scheduled task is actually logged in.